# Error:Execution failed for task org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 'finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, compiler-errors, static-libraries, build.gradle, google-api-client

i am adding that library but can not run my code

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev70-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
}
```

Comment: can you edit the question with complete gradle code?

Answer (score 2):

**Same type (Old-New version)** `compile` library causes this problem .

The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools 21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager before attempting to configure your app for multidex.

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

My advise

Use

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

avoid

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

I guess problem is here

```
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
```

After Edit

```
  apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.notepad"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
   /* compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'*/
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev70-1.14.1-beta.jar')
    /*compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')*/
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar')
  /*  compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: @JitendraRathore comment out `compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'`

Answer (score 0):

this error is common for older version...
use this code gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        //Enabling mutidex
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

After enabling multidex use this library in dependence

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I think it works perfect..